# Bit ordering / Endianness flac decoding

Tags: c++, c, audio, decoding, flac

I'm currently trying to write a FLAC to WAV transcoder as an exercise in C++, and I am currently struggling a bit the wording of the FLAC format regarding bit ordering.

Here is the (little) section talking about ordering:

> All numbers used in a FLAC bitstream are integers; there are no floating-point representations. All numbers are big-endian coded. All numbers are unsigned unless otherwise specified.

Does this apply to bit-ordering, as well as byte-ordering?
More specifically, if I read, say, a 7 bits value, do I get the most-significant bit 1st?

Comment: How are you proposing to read individual bits?

Comment: You could [swap the bits](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR) after reading them. That sounds like an overkill though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit ordering should never be an issue unless you're using a `struct` with bitfields (which is a good reason to avoid then).

Also, you can only read data one byte at a time.  If you want to read 7 bits out of a byte, you need to apply a bitmask to the byte value.

For example, if a byte contains one value in the high order bit and another in the low order 7 bits, you would extract them as follows:

```
field1 = (byte & 0x80) >> 7;
field2 = byte & 0x7f;
```

Comment: Ok, so let's take the example of a [metadata block header](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_header).

I expect in order, 1 bit to know if it is the last, 7 bits for the type then 24bits (big-endian) for the length.
The 1st byte i read from there, bit0 is the last flag, and bit1-bit7 is the type. To get the data i would simply do:
`flag = byte & 1, type = (byte >> 1)`
Is that a good understanding of the ordering?

Comment: @Pulo That field has valid value of 0-127 so extract it with `value & 0x7f`

Comment: Ok so, from what i understand, that means that the most significant bit is the last flag, and the type is built with the lower bits.
The spec say i should expect first a the flag, the the type is built from the lower bits, and the last flag from the high bit.
Is that a good assessment of what's going on?

Comment: @Pulo Correct,  So you would need to do `flag = byte >> 7` and `type = byte & 0xf`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed to know. Would you mind add this to the answer for future reference and I'll accept it gladly.